# Java - Adding multiple maps into 2D object array

Tags: java, arrays, object, hashmap

I am very new to Java and please bear with my skills.
The below java statements helps save `mapOne` object in `tabArray[0][0]`:

```
Object[][] tabArray = null;
Map<String, String> mapOne = readDbConfig();
tabArray = new Object[][] { { mapOne } };
```

I have another map object (`mapTwo`) and I can save both at once with below code:

```
    Object[][] tabArray = null;
    Map<String, String> mapOne = readDbConfig();
    Map<String, String> mapTwo = readDbConfig();
    tabArray = new Object[][] { { mapOne }, { mapTwo } };
```

In the above case maps are stored as below:

`mapOne` in `tabArray[0][0]` and `mapTwo` in `tabArray[1][0]`

Questions:

1. If I have 100 maps, how can I get them added in a single statement?
2. To be more specific, how can I save map object into a specific index of a 2D array?

I have the below code which throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at line 4:

```
Map<String, String> dataMap = null;
dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
dataMap = readDbConfig();
tabArray[cj][0] = dataMap;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below solution:

```
Object[][] tabArray = null;
int numberOfMaps = 2;
tabArray = new Object[numberOfMaps][1];//<<< This did the trick
tabArray[0][0] = dataMapOne;
tabArray[1][0] = dataMapTwo;
```

Answer (score 0):

If readDbConfig method "generates" you new maps, you can just use a simple loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 tabArray[i][0] = readDbConfig();
```

Or if you have some iterable container with maps inside, you can iterate through this container

```
for (Map<String, String> el : container) {
 tabArray[i][0] = el;
 i++;
}
```

Comment: I have the below code which throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at line 4: 'Map<String, String> dataMap = null; dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); dataMap = readDbConfig(); tabArray[cj][0] = dataMap;'

Comment: It means that you are trying to reach outside array bounds, i.e:
    int[] tabArray = new int[10];
    tabArray[42] = 5;
Array has size of 10, so you can't access cell 42.